# Reading a CSV with observations containing a "–" sign

Tags: r, csv

I have an excel file with the first column looking like this:

```
Age
17–20
17–20
17–20
17–20
21–24
21–24
21–24
21–24
25–29
25–29
25–29
25–29
30–34
30–34
30–34
30–34
35–39
35–39
35–39
35–39
40–49
40–49
40–49
40–49
50–59
50–59
50–59
50–59
60+
60+
60+
60+
```

I would like to read this into R without changing each individual observation in excel. I used the following code:

```
df39 <- read.csv("AutoCollision.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",
                 colClasses=c("character","character","numeric","numeric"))
```

However, this makes the data set look like this:

```
            Age Vehicle_Use Severity Claim_Count
1  17\xd020    Pleasure   250.48          21
2  17\xd020  DriveShort   274.78          40
3  17\xd020   DriveLong   244.52          23
4  17\xd020    Business   797.80           5
5  21\xd024    Pleasure   213.71          63
6  21\xd024  DriveShort   298.60         171
7  21\xd024   DriveLong   298.13          92
8  21\xd024    Business   362.23          44
9  25\xd029    Pleasure   250.57         140
10 25\xd029  DriveShort   248.56         343
11 25\xd029   DriveLong   297.90         318
12 25\xd029    Business   342.31         129
13 30\xd034    Pleasure   229.09         123
14 30\xd034  DriveShort   228.48         448
15 30\xd034   DriveLong   293.87         361
16 30\xd034    Business   367.46         169
17 35\xd039    Pleasure   153.62         151
18 35\xd039  DriveShort   201.67         479
19 35\xd039   DriveLong   238.21         381
20 35\xd039    Business   256.21         166
21 40\xd049    Pleasure   208.59         245
22 40\xd049  DriveShort   202.80         970
23 40\xd049   DriveLong   236.06         719
24 40\xd049    Business   352.49         304
25 50\xd059    Pleasure   207.57         266
26 50\xd059  DriveShort   202.67         859
27 50\xd059   DriveLong   253.63         504
28 50\xd059    Business   340.56         162
29      60+    Pleasure   192.00         260
30      60+  DriveShort   196.33         578
31      60+   DriveLong   259.79         312
32      60+    Business   342.58          96
```

Why did it change the minus signs to "\xd0" and how could I go about fixing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to specify the `encoding` in `read.table` to `utf-16` or so

Comment: Would that come after the read.csv step?

Comment: No, it is just the reading part.  Replace the `read.csv` with `read.table` which also have the `encoding` argument.  May be `read.csv` also have.

Comment: I tried this: read.table("AutoCollision.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",encoding="utf-16")

Comment: And got the following error: Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, numerals = numerals,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<d0>20'

Comment: you may need the correct encoding for hat.

Comment: The `readr` package has `guess_encoding()` which might help identifying the encoding of your data.

Comment: I tried guess_encoding(df39) and got the following message: Warning message:
In if (stringi::stri_enc_isascii(lines)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: The data set is online. Perhaps I could add a link?

Comment: You could just clean it up after the fact with something like `df39$Age = sub('\\\\xd0', '-', df39$Age)`